# for loop that uses selenium to fill a data frame. Why does it only fill the first row?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of elements from a web page that I want to iterate through. I want to click on each element then grab data from the page that element linked to.  I need to save this data to a data frame.  The problem here is that only the data from the first element is being entered into the data frame.  The data frame should have information from 84 different properties.

Why does the data frame only have the data from the first element in `properties`?

**List of elements:**

```
print(properties[0:5])

[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="93C94F07-6E83-4FCF-BC81-C1094B2D57FC", element="node-E0326EE3-BB10-4ED5-A705-257D151516B4")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="93C94F07-6E83-4FCF-BC81-C1094B2D57FC", element="node-07A8FADF-A8A3-4A98-94D6-3F59493685DE")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="93C94F07-6E83-4FCF-BC81-C1094B2D57FC", element="node-1494D76E-B621-45CC-B808-F0D66B1CE9D6")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="93C94F07-6E83-4FCF-BC81-C1094B2D57FC", element="node-1B28849F-78F9-48F1-8A35-2DD806DA647B")>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="93C94F07-6E83-4FCF-BC81-C1094B2D57FC", element="node-378D2946-54EF-4570-8070-CC3D25D1F83B")>]
```

**For loop:**

```
for index, prop in enumerate(properties):
    try:
        prop.click()
        url = driver.current_url
        html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        details = soup.find_all('p')
        details = [i.get_text() for i in details][5:20]
        details = [i.split(':') for i in details]
        columns = [i[0] for i in details]
        data = [[i[1][1:] for i in details]]
        df = df.append(data)
        if index <1:
            df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
        else:
            df = df.append(data)
    except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:  
        pass
```

**Dataframe (should be 84 rows instead of 1)**

```
print(df)

Property Address    Price   Rent    Type    Class   Square Footage  Bedroom Bathroom    Year Built  Taxes   Insurance   Operating Expense   Down Payment    Cash on Cash ROI    Monthly Cash Flow

100 Example Dr      $75,000 $700    SFR     B       630             1       1.0         1925        $1,020  $400        N/A                 $15,000         18%                 $186
```

Comment: Not a Pandas expert, but usually, `.append()` modifies its object in place and returns `None`. What happens if you use `df.append(data)` instead of `df = df.append(data)`?

Comment: Use print Function to see where things goes wrong. Print df right under df = df.append(data) and see what it gives you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:
`df = df.append(data)`

`df.append` method returns `None`.

Change this line to the next:
`df.append(data)`

More information here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists